# Correct pg_hba.conf to allow script to run locally with a specific db-user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've got a working postgreSQL database with following pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
hostssl all             dbadmin         my.ip.at.home/32       md5
```

Which, to my understanding is correct, and only allows local connections and from my home-ip via SSL. Both via a md5 password.

I now want a local bash script to run some things on the databases (backups). For this I created a new user `backup_user`; as the script needs to run autonomous my thoughts were to create a line for this user to trust from the the `lo`:

```
host   all           backup_user     127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

But when I login via SSH and run this command I have to type the password....

```
psql -U backup_user -p 5454
```

What is the best way to let the script do its thing?
If it matters, I want this script to sun: [Automated Backup](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux)

Comment: Why not set the auth method to md5 for the backup user, and use a .pgpass file? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: Hmm because I didn't kow of the existence off .pgpass.... Where on my (ubunutu) server should I find this file?

Comment: For connecting through Unix domain socket (and that's how you connect as you don't specify a host via `-h`) [replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) that line with `local all backup_user  peer` and move it at just after the first line.

Comment: O.K. I don't want to use .pgpass as the password is stored in there as plain text.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev When I do that and change peer into trust; I can login without pass from the command line psql-command. But If I run the script it does ask for a password....

Comment: Then move your original line just before this one: `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5`.

Comment: That did the trick :)

Comment: @Milen, I think your last comment would look good as (accepted) answer.

Comment: [This related answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100) might be of help also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the backup user to connect locally from the database server. I assume the backup is running on a dedicated backup account on the OS.

Using pg_hba.conf you can specify like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE USER   ADDRESS METHOD
local   all      backup_user    peer map=local_peers_backup_user
```

(method peer (with local/peer an address is not needed))

combine this with a pg_ident.conf like:

```
# MAPNAME                SYSTEM-USERNAME   PG-USERNAME
local_peers_backup_user  postgres          backup_user
local_peers_backup_user  OSBKPUSER         backup_user
```

This allows the os user postgres and OSBKUSER to connect to all databases in the cluster as the postgres database user named backup_user, using peer authentication. This works using sockets, on linux.

connected as your OSBKPUSER running `psql` suffices to get connected as backup_user, assuming that you already prepared the environment variables for the OSBKPUSER and OSBKPUSER has only 1 map. Otherwise run `psql -U backup_user`.

This connect method is secure, if you trust that the access to your dbserver is secured.